# Can't call function from .dll created in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I'm able to call function from DLL created in C (.c file), but i can't do it from DLL created in C++ (.cpp file). I want to find out why it doesn't work in .cpp file.

I'm trying to call function `printword()` from a simple DLL, created with Visual Studio 2022:

```
// FILE: dllmain.cpp

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


__declspec(dllexport) void printword() {
    std::cout << "word" << std::endl;    //with printf() doesn't work too
}
```

And when i call function the way like this:

```
int main() {

    HMODULE dll;
    if ((dll = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\Visual Studio projects\\Dll1\\x64\\Debug\\Dll1.dll")) == NULL) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    FARPROC func;
    if ((func = GetProcAddress(dll, "printword")) == NULL) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

`GetProcAddress` throws error `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND`

But if i create DLL in file with `.c` suffix `printword()` function calls correctly (with same code above):

```
// FILE: dllmain.c

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


__declspec(dllexport) void printword() {
    printf("word\n");
}
```

Comment: Possibly a name mangling issue. You might need a Module Definition file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exported function's name will get [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) when the DLL is compiled. You must use the mangled name in `GetProcAddress()` in order for it to work. For example, the mangled name
in MSVC is:

```cpp
GetProcAddress(dll, "?printword@@YAXXZ");
```

Or, you could add this to the function's body to tell the compiler not to mangle it:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) void printword() {
    #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__"=" __FUNCDNAME__)
    printf("word\n");
}
```

Alternatively, adding [`extern "C"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c) will also solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Review and try the recommendations from this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-cyrl-rs/cpp/build/exporting-cpp-functions-for-use-in-c-language-executables?view=msvc-170

Example

```
// MyCFuncs.h
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int MyFunc(long parm1);
```

Key part being extern "C"

[I accidentally posted the link for importing instead of exporting earlier - corrected for the export article]